# Kucoin .net sdk, problems with websockets connections

Tags: websocket, exchangewebservices, broker

I am using **[Kucoin SDK](https://github.com/JKorf/Kucoin.Net)** for .Net created by a third party, the problem I have is that the connections to the websockets are not constant, that is, they do not work 24/7, the documentation I found about it SDK is very limited.
This is how I am configuring the websockets client.

```
Cliente_Kucoin = new KucoinSocketClient(new Objects.KucoinSocketClientOptions()
{
    ApiCredentials = new Objects.KucoinApiCredentials("xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxx"),
    AutoReconnect = true,
    ReconnectInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    LogLevel = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace,
    SocketSubscriptionsCombineTarget = 2
});
```

And so, I make the subscriptions to the sockets.

```
private async void Listener_Cryptos()
{

    var BTC = await ClienteKucoin.Spot.SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync(BTC.Tickets, BTC.Trade);
    var ETH = await ClienteKucoin.Spot.SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync(ETH.Tickets, ETH.Trade);
    var BNB = await ClienteKucoin.Spot.SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync(BNB.Tickets, BNB.Trade);
    var ADA = await ClienteKucoin.Spot.SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync(ADA.Tickets, ADA.Trade);
    var XRP = await ClienteKucoin.Spot.SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync(XRP.Tickets, XRP.Trade);

}
```